# jQuery - Get the value of closest textbox and assign it into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the value of the closest textbox and assign it into a variable? Then after getting the value, change the current value of that textbox by multiplying it by the value of previous textbox. I have three instances of divs with the same input elements so I think .closest() or .next() can help me. Here is a snippet of my code

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <b>1</b>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ignoreThisCheckbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="10"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <b>2</b>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ignoreThisCheckbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="10"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <b>3</b>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ignoreThisCheckbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="10"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("input[name=quantity]").each(function(){
    $(this).bind("change keyup", function(){
        var q = $(this).val();
        var p = parseFloat($(this).closest("input[name=price]").val()).toFixed(2);
        var amount = q * p;
        $(this).closest("input[name=price]").val(amount)
        console.log(amount);
    })
})
```

non working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/c6yfS/

Thank you for responses

**/* NOTE */**

The purpose of the checkbox is just to show that I have a checkbox in between the two elements concerned.

Comment: The .closest() method begins its search with the element itself before progressing up the DOM tree. To get the value of other element you might need to use .next() or .prev(). You can also try this but I am not sure `var p = parseFloat($(this).closest("input[name=price]").closest("input[name=price]").val()).toFixed(2);`

Comment: I tried your snippet and it still giving me NaN result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by other posters, you can use .siblings as .closest searches up the DOM tree (i.e. parent elements). However there is also a logic error in your code as the price you retrieve is never the right per unit price if quantity is changed. You will need a separate unit price hidden value perhaps to facilitate this

Check out the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6yfS/1/

Comment: Thanks! your solution worked for on the demo I have. But unfortunately, the same solution didn't work for my actual code. The value of those fields are dynamically inserted by a while loop on mysql_fetch_assoc (PHP is the lang btw). I guess the problem is now on the loop.

Comment: It is working now. I've made a workaround on my code, but still using your solution.

Answer (score 2):

it's better to use `data` attribute in order to calculating correctly:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <b>1</b>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ignoreThisCheckbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="text" name="price" data-value="10"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[name=quantity]').on("change keyup", function(){
        var q = 0;
        var p = 0;
        var amount = 0;
        q = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        p = parseInt($(this).siblings("input[name='price']").data('value'), 10);
        amount = q * p;
        if (amount) {
          $(this).siblings("input[name='price']").val(amount)
        console.log(amount);
        } else {
          $(this).siblings("input[name='price']").val('Please specify the quantity')        
        }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c6yfS/9/)

Comment: price value is dynamic, value of 10 is just for demo

Comment: @fart-y-goer 10 is radix of parseInt() function, it has nothing to do with value of 10.

Comment: -1 No No. Doesn't grab the correct input and double event binding makes it not work twice.

Comment: `data('value')` Why you no `.val()`.

Comment: @iambriansreed because the value of input changes after each change event and it's not 10 afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`.closest` is used to find the closest element up the DOM tree.  What you are looking for is `siblings` or `next` | `prev`.

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/next/

So

```
$(this).siblings("input[name='price']").val(amount);
```

**Edit**

Here is the full working JS:

```
$("input[name=quantity]").each(function(){
    $(this).bind("change keyup", function(){
        var $thi,q,$p,p;
        $thi = $(this);
        q = $thi.val();
        $p = $(this).siblings("input[name='price']");
        p = parseFloat($p.val()).toFixed(2);
        $p.val(q * p);
    });
});
```

Comment: I made a an edit, change `price` to `'price'`.  You still have another error. But the correct input is getting selected when you make that change.

Comment: I posted the full working version.  I got it to work as above in your JSFiddle.

Comment: -1 no need for the `:first` as there is only one sibling with that name and you double bound the event.

Comment: You are right about the `:first`.  I removed that but don't knock me for just refactoring enough code to get it work.  It wasn't my intention to make a bullet proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

for clarity I've just add a total field
You can solve it with this code :

$("input[name=quantity], input[name=price]")
    .each( function(){ $(this).on( {'keyup': function(){ var j0=$(this).nextAll("input[name=total]"); j0.val( j0.prevAll("input[name=quantity]").val() * j0.prevAll("input[name=price]").val() ) } } ) } );

[Click here to see the working "Fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/anonymouzee/rCLnJ/)